# What part of an app should be responsible for notifying SignalR clients?

Tags: architecture, ravendb, signalr

I'm using RavenDB and my DAL receives a notification when certain documents get added to the database. The entire flow looks like this:

**WPF -> WCF (hosts SignalR, too) -> BLL -> DAL -> RavenDB**

When a document is added, this is the what happens:

1. RavenDB document added
2. DAL receives notice of change and fires event
3. WCF subscribes to that event and sends message to all SignalR
   clients
4. All WPF clients receive this notice and update the UI to show this new document

This seems wrong because my WCF service has a direct dependency on the DAL.

Another option is to have the DAL notify the SignalR clients, but then that can seem wrong because the DAL shouldn't be concerned with that. Should it?

What part of the entire application should be responsible for actually using SignalR to notify all connected clients?

To be clear, the part that I'm having a hard time with is the red line (#2) below. I'm having a hard time letting the WCF service take a dependency on the DAL.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service no doubt depends on your BLL which in turn depends on the DAL right? Why not route the event out of your DAL and then through your BLL so it is the event on the BLL that the service subscribes to?

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I thought of that, but I didn't know how I felt about creating another event in the BLL to report on the event in the DAL. That may be the way to go though, so my service doesn't depend on a data implementation.

Comment: Actually, I may have an even better idea. Why have the WCF service involved at all? I just need to move the entire responsibility from the WCF service to the BLL. The BLL will subscribe the the DAL event, and the BLL will invoke SignalR. Done. No WCF necessary in this process.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a decoupled way of letting SignalR update clients, my library is on nuget 
Install using

```
Install-Package SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
```

Wiki: https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

The framework needs a service bus or "EventAggregator" to work, I have not hardcoded it for a specific service bus or event aggregator so you have to create a proxy for it, Caliburn micro has a light weight in process event aggregator you can install using

```
Install-Package Caliburn.Micro.EventAggregator
```

You then need to create a proxy between my library and CM.EA, after that any message published in your data access layer will automatically be forwarded to the clients. They can listen to events like

```
signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(MyApp.Events.TestEvent, this.onTestEvent, this);
```

You can also use generic events like

```
signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(MyApp.Events.MyGenericEvent.of("System.String"), this.onMyGenericEvent, this);
```

*edit:* Just realized you are using WPF and not JS for the clients, sorry for that. Currently the lib is target at web apps. But off course it should work for C# clients too, will put C# client support on the road map right away!

**Update:** A .NET client is now available, Server is still IIS hosted only.

```
Install-Package SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.DotNet
```

Wiki: https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki/.NET-Client

A .NET class can listen to events like this

```
public class MyViewModel : IHandle<MyEvent>
{
   public MyViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) 
   {
      eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
   }
   public void Handle(MyEvent message)
   {
      //Act on MyEvent
   }
}
```

See wiki for more info

Comment: That looks interesting. Thanks, Anders!

Answer (score 0):

Your work flow seems okay to me, but I suppose it depends on how soon SignalR gets the notification. If it were me I would update the clients from the WCF as soon as I could. Making the DAL layer responsible for sending the message to all the clients is not the right place to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Derek. The notification indeed happens instantly. Perhaps the WCF service needs to depend on the DAL, but I keep thinking there has to be a better way.